# Reading nested propery from yaml in spring boot configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, yaml, spring-data-mongodb

For the project I am currently working on, I am trying to load the nested value in from yaml to the spring-boot application I've been trying different things from here and there but nothing appears to be working.

hear is how my **database-server.yaml** looks like:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: database-service
  data:
    mongodb.host: <hostname>
    mongodb.port: 27017
    mongodb.uri: mongodb://<hostname>/<db>
```

I want to access the mongodb.host and mongodb.port.

Entry point of spring boot looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("abc.def.testrun")
public class DatabaseOperationServiceWebApp
{
   public static void main(String... args)
   {
      System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "database-server");
      SpringApplication.run(DatabaseOperationServiceWebApp.class, args);
   }
}
```

hear is how I am trying to retrieve the value: I think I am doing something wrong here, but having no idea what, because I reading different things on different tutorials. So, kind of know idea what exactly needs to be done here.

```
    @Configuration
    @Component
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    public class TestRunDatabaseOperationConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration
    {

       @Override
       protected String getDatabaseName()
       {
          return "db";
       }

       @Value("${mongodb.host}")
       private String host;
       @Value("${mongodb.port}")
       private String port;
       //more code
    }
```

can you tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Name is `spring.data.mongodb.host` not `mongodb.host`. Why aren't you letting Spring Boot configure the things for you? It has auto config support for mongo (that is why the properties exist).

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please add your comment as an answer I'll accept it, I am using auto config for configuring the mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Try this config and let Spring Boot configure the rest: [Example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-mongodb)

**application.yml**

```
spring:
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: <hostname>
            port: 27017
            database: <dbname>
            username: <usernamr>
            password: ******
```